# Getting information from a list

Tags: python

I need some help with my code. I recently started learning Python from a friend. Usually, if I have a problem he will show me what to do, but he is out on holiday for a few weeks, so he can not help. I need to create a price comparison tool to compare the prices of products entered. I can do most of the code, I just need help with how to get stuff out of a list. I can gather all the info and put it into a list, I'm just not sure how to get it out again. I need it to display the average unit price of all products entered, the cheapest overall product, the most expensive overall product and a recommendation for the cheapest unit price in the budget that the user sets. I'm not sure how to gather this info from inside the list. Any help would be appreciated. This is my code so far: (I have left out functions)

```
keep_going = ""
while keep_going == "":

    sum_table = []
    count = 0
    unit_type = ""

    print("Welcome to the price comparison tool!")
    print()
    how_much = num_check("How much money do you have to spend? $", float, 1, 100)

    get_prod = True
    while get_prod:

        if count < 1:
            p_name = len_check("What is the name of the first product? ")
        elif 0 < count:
            p_name = len_check("Please enter another product, or type XXX to bring up summary ")
            if p_name.lower() == "xxx":
                break

        unit = num_check("Is the product in g/ml or kg/L? (enter 1 for g/ml or 2 for kg/l) ", int, 1, 2)
        if unit == 1:
            unit_type = "grams/millilitres"
        elif unit == 2:
            unit_type = "kilograms/litres"

        p_mass = num_check("What is the mass of '{}' in {}? " .format(p_name, unit_type), float, 1, 1000)
        if unit == 2:
            p_mass = p_mass*1000
        p_price = num_check("What is the price of '{}' in dollars? $" .format(p_name), float, 0.1, 100)
        p_average = p_price/(p_mass/1000)

        row = [p_name, p_mass, p_price, p_average]
        sum_table.append(row)
        count += 1

    for i in sum_table:
        if i[2] > how_much:
            sum_table.remove(i)

    print()
    print("--- Product Summary ---")
    print("All items over-budget have been removed! ")
    print("Name\tMass in g/ml\tPrice\tUnit price per kg")
    for i in sum_table:
        print(i)

    print()
    keep_going = input("Press <enter> to go again or any other key to quit")
    print()
```

Comment: Consider adding comments to your code to explain what you're doing or what problems you have

Comment: Also, what are `len_check()` and `num_check()`?

Comment: there are many built-in functions(min,max,sum etc...) that do what you are trying to achieve, just google them and you will find a lot of info.

Comment: Wait for them to get back or do some research: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 1):

In the way you are showing it, the different items, you can pull each item out of the row.

For example:

```
>>> row = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a,b,c,d,e = row
>>> print a,b,c,d,e
1 2 3 4 5
```

Thus loop over the rows and use `p_name, p_mass, p_price, p_average = row[i]`

Now (as an example), set max-p-index as the index of the row showing the maximum price. and max-p as the actual maximum price value. You can do the similar calculations for every value that you want to keep track of, as well as building up the averages. Once you finish the loop, you will have all the values that you need appropriately.

```
if max-p < p_price:
    max-p = p_price
    max-p-index = i
```

You can get the cheapest price, unit prices, averages, etc in the same way within this loop over row after you have removed the overpriced rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull information out of arrays by adding brackets and a number.
So let's define the array first:

```
    >>> list = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

Then, let's print the entire list by entering this:

```
    >>> print (list)
```

The following result:

```
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Now we call individual numbers by doing this. We add a pair of brackets at the end. In the brackets, you put a number which calls the number. The number you enter into the brackets should be a number from the order of the list. For example:

```
    >>> list[0]
    1

    >>>list[1]
    3
```

It prints the number you put, but in the order. Zero is the starting number. This is like a table:

> List 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9
>
> Call 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
> or... -4 | -3 | -2 | -1|

You can also make it negatives
Just add the brackets. And yeah. Have fun and good luck